# "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, non-static

Thanks for taking your time to help me.

I have a problem with the "non-static ..." error and I don't know why. Here's the code

```
public class Klient {
    public static String output = "test";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9898);
        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            output = BR.readLine();
            Server2.setTekst(output);
        }
```

(This is just a part of the code. I know this ends while paraphrasing)

And the other class:

```
public class Server2 extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    konsol = new JTextPane();
    konsol.setEditable(false);

    public void setTekst(String tekst) {
        konsol.setText(tekst);
    }

    public void run() {
        instance = new Server2();
        instance.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Again, this is also just a part of the code. I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

make this method as static

```
public static void setTekst(String tekst){
    konsol.setText(tekst);
}
```

Comment: this is correct @SpringLearner i think the OP should make a lot of changes i hope you can make your post a  **community wiki** so we can explain more

Comment: @SpringLearner I already tried that, and am met with the exact same error. This time it is the following code that gives the error. 
    konsol.setText(tekst);

Comment: @Bassusour show the line number where you are geting error

Comment: @SpringLearner I edited the comment above with the location where i get the error, but I'll do it in a new comment aswell. 
I get it in the konsol.setText(tekst);

Comment: @Bassusour may be konsol is non static

Comment: @SpringLearner thanks for the help, now i dont get that error :)
However, i ran into a new problem. The text wont show up. I think I will make a new thread for this, after i give it a try myself